# Expose SQL Server Analysis Services to users

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, sql-server

is there a convenient way to expose SSAS to users in following scenario?

User's are located in Local Area Network, thru it users can access in frontend part of separated network and thru it they can access to backend part of separated network in which lies SSAS service.

User's should be able to connecto to SSAS with MS Excel.

Comment: I'm confused, as long as the network topology doesn't block traffic on the right ports (default: 2383) then you should be able to create a direct connection from excel to SSAS.  Whats preventing you from this this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally there's an application server in the way, such as a web technology/Sharepoint/etc - so the end users connect to that app server, and the app server consumes the data from Analysis Services or SQL Server relational data.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately SharePoint Enterprise (with Excel services) is too expensive for my budget. My application would be just Excel connected to SSAS :-(

Comment: Perhaps this can be used as a solution?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917711.aspx#EXH